# Calculate distance an object needs to be appear no larger than X?

Tags: geometry

I'm not 100% sure the best way to word the question, my apologies.

I'm working on an app where there is an object of variable size. I want to keep the object smaller than X pixels in width, or X% of the screen width, etc.

I know the size of the object in 3D space. I know the width of the object on screen. I know the current distance the object is from the camera in 3D space.

I'm trying to figure out the equation that would basically say: "If this 1m wide square is currently 2m away from the camera, and is 500 pixels wide, how far away would it have to be to be 400 pixels wide?"

While this is taking place in 3D space, the object I'm working with is 2 dimensional and is always directly facing the camera - there is no depth or rotation to worry about.

I cannot simply resize the square, it interacts with other objects in the app, and it's visible size needs to be set by it's distance from the camera.

Comment: Do you have a real camera, or is it simulated in software?  In a real camera the distance from the lens to the image will change as the distance to the object changes.  In a software simulation, that may well not happen.  How accurate do you need to be?  When the angular size of the object is small you can just multiply the distance by the inverse of the size reduction, so to go from $500$ to $400$ pixels you multiply the distance by $\frac 54$

Comment: Its a simulation, a simple camera in Unity with a field of view of 60 degrees. Nothing fancy going on, no zooming or focal length changes. I'll give what you wrote a shot... it sounds too simple given the math I've been unsuccessfully trying :)

Comment: Well heck. A quick and simple test with a 1m cube 1.547m from the camera that was the screen's full width, moved to 6.188m away (4x the distance) was exactly the same size as a .25m cube 1.547m from the camera. Its blowing my mind that I overlooked something so absurdly simple. Thanks!